# Relational join of two datasets

Tags: beginner, functional-programming, scala, data-mining, etl

## Front Matter

I'm learning Scala and have not gotten used to functional programming and the language.  I'm hoping a review of my naively implemented code can help me bridge my object-oriented ways to something more functional and Scala-prescribed.

I've uploaded all of my code here: https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2209023/

## Problem

I have to merge 2 data sets and product a XML output.

- one dataset is entity data, e.g. `entity.csv`

```
name, ip,
name1,,
name1,1.2.3.4,
name3,1.2.3.4,
name4,1.2.3.4,
```

- another data set is streaming data, e.g. `streaming.csv`

```
name, event,
name1, event1,
name1, event2,
name2, event3,
name3, event4,
```

## Concerns

I was not sure how to merge the 2 datasets without storing the data in a list of model objects.  Is there a functional programming pattern to do this type of joining/merging?

I thought that if I get a list of objects then I can feed it to a templating engine to produce the XML output.  Is there a functional programming pattern to render the merged data as XML?

## Approach

My naive approach is to:

1. get a list of all the device names
2. iterate through this list and fill out all of the relevant data needed for the XML output
3. feed the list to a templating engine to product the XML file

   - This part has not been completed yet

## Implementation

### Step 1: Get List of Devices

In `Main.scala`, get a list of all the devices, e.g. `devices_list`:

```
  val streaming = spark.read
    ...
    .load("src/main/resources/streaming.csv") // using steaming data because we want devices that has events
  ...
  val devices_df = streaming
    .select(
      "name",  
    )
    .distinct

  val devices_list = new Devices(devices_df).devices()
```

In `Devices.scala`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, Row}
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

class Devices(
  val devices_df: Dataset[Row],
){
  private var _devices = List[Device]()

  def devices(): List[Device] = {
    _get_devices()
  }

  private[this] def _get_devices(): List[Device] = {
    if (_devices.isEmpty) {
      _devices = _initialize_list_of_devices()
    }
    _devices
  }

  private[this] def _initialize_list_of_devices(): List[Device] = {
    val devices_list = ListBuffer[Device]()
    for (device <- devices_df.collect()) {
      devices_list += new Device(
        device.getAs[String]("name"),
      )
    }
    devices_list.toList
  }
}
```

In `Device.scala`:

```
class Device(
  val name: String,
){
  private var _events = List[String]()
  private var _ip = ""

  def getName(): String = {
    name
  }
  def getEvents(): List[String] = {
    _events
  }
  def setEvents(events: List[String]): Unit = {
    _events = events
  }
  def getIp(): String = {
    _ip
  }
  def setIp(ip: String): Unit = {
    _ip = ip
  }
}
```

### Step 2: Fill Out Data for Each Device

In `Main.scala`, iterate through the list of devices and use `DataFiller` class:

```
  for (device <- devices_list) {
    new DataFiller(
      device,
      streaming,
      entity,
    ).fill()
  }
```

In `DataFiller`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession, Row}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

class DataFiller(
  var device: Device,
  val streaming: Dataset[Row],
  val entity: Dataset[Row],
){
  def fill() = {
    _fillEvents()
    _fillIp()
  }

  private[this] def _fillEvents(): Unit = {
    device.setEvents(
      streaming
        .filter(col("name") === device.getName())
        .select("event")
        .rdd.map(event => {
          event.getAs[String]("event")
        })
        .collect.toList
    )
  }
  private[this] def _fillIp(): Unit = {
    val ip_column = device_network_info
      .filter(col("name") === device.getName())
      .filter(row => {
        !row.getAs[String]("ip").isEmpty
      })
      .select("ip")

    var ip:Any = ""
    if(!ip_column.rdd.isEmpty) {
      ip = ip_column.first().get(0)
      device.setIp(ip.toString)
    }
  }
}
```

### Step 3: Output to XML

I have not implemented this part yet.  I was thinking to use a templating engine and render the `devices_list`.  I was not sure how to do this functionally without having a list with all of the data in model classes.

Thank you for your time

Here's the entire `Main.scala`:

````
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Main extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local") 
    .getOrCreate()

  val streaming = spark.read
    ...
    .load("src/main/resources/streaming.csv")
  val entity = spark.read
    ...
    .load("src/main/resources/entity.csv")

  val devices_df = streaming
    .select(
      "name",  
    )
    .distinct

  val devices_list = new Devices(devices_df).devices()

  for (device <- devices_list) {
    new DataFiller(
      device,
      streaming,
      entity,
    ).fill()
  }

  // output devices_list to XML

  spark.stop()
}
```
````

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: @TobySpeight thank you for your help. I think that’s a better description than anything I can think.